# Set up eth0 network interface using DHCP in initramfs

Tags: 10.04, networking, dhcp, ethernet, initramfs

I created my own initramfs script (based on live-initramfs) and I need set up network connection (using DHCP) to get remote file. 
So what do I need to add to initramfs hook file (ifconfig, dhclient?).
And how to write my initramfs script?
Now I am trying something like this:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/network  # needed by ifup
modprobe af_packet         # for DHCP?
udevadm trigger            
udevadm settle  
ifup eth0                  #???
```

for ifup I need /etc/network/interfaces file to have:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But generally I don't know what exactly need to be done for network device to work properly in initramfs.

Any idea or help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `ipconfig` via the kernel's `ip=` command-line option in `grub.cfg` (or `pxelinux.cfg` or however you boot your kernel).  I'm not aware of a man page for it, but there is a [`README.ipconfig` file in the klibc Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/kinit/ipconfig/README.ipconfig) and installed at `/usr/share/doc/klibc-utils/README.ipconfig.gz`.  So your `/etc/default/grub` might have a line such as the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ip=:::::eth0:dhcp"
```

You may need to make a simple script in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top` that sources the `functions` file and then calls the `configure_networking` function, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /scripts/functions
configure_networking
```

(I had mistakenly thought `configure_networking` was called by default, but something has to explicitly call it—either your own script or one from a package.  In my case, it was called from `open-iscsi`.)